# Whitelabel WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

How do I change a WordPress Theme name and keep it changed after an update? I have tried renaming the wp-content/themes/ folder, and the name inside the style.css file as well. However, the theme goes back to its original name after the update.

Perhaps there is a plugin that automatically overwrites the theme name and renames its folder to make it white label?

Steps that I have already done:

```
wp-content/themes/<renamed theme> - Changed theme name
Changed name inside theme's style.css file
```

Anything I can do to make the theme name automatically renamed even after the theme's automatic update (have to keep it due to security).

Answer (score 0):

Change the name in the /themes/[renamed theme]/style.css
The line > Theme Name: [change it here]

If you update a theme via the WordPress admin it will overwrite all of its content. If you don't want it to update, try also changing the version to something really high in the style.css.

Example:
Version: 99.99

If you still want the renamed theme to update automatically it will always update all files. This can't be avoided.

Why not just use a child theme instead? https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/